# Call read function in knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I would like to know how to call read function. When I write in value: valueView calls the write function but I want at the end of the function make a call to read function. There is some method to alert read in knockout?

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: valueView" placeholder="VALUE">

self.valueView = ko.pureComputed({
        read: function () {
        var value = “John”;
        return value;
        },
        write: function (value) {
        some code;
        callRead() ¿???
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the current value by simply calling it as a function with no parameters.

`self.valueView()` Executes the Read function,
`self.valueView(someValue)` Executes the Write function, passing `someValue` to it.

You can also force the computed to reevaluate and update other dependent observables/computeds using the `valueHasMutated` method, ie `self.valueView.valueHasMutated()`

Answer (score 2):

Reading *(getting)* from an observable can be done by "calling the function". 
Writing *(setting)* it can be done by passing a value to it.

To get a value inside a computed without creating subscriptions, you can use the `peek` method.

```js
var myObservable = ko.observable(1);
console.log(myObservable()); // Prints 1

myObservable(2);
console.log(myObservable()); // Prints 2

console.log(myObservable.peek()); // Also prints 2
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

You can see this being used in the example on the knockout writable observable [documentation page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html):

```
this.firstName = ko.observable('Planet');
this.lastName = ko.observable('Earth');

this.fullName = ko.pureComputed({
  read: function () {
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
  },
  write: function (value) {
    var lastSpacePos = value.lastIndexOf(" ");
    if (lastSpacePos > 0) { // Ignore values with no space character
      this.firstName(value.substring(0, lastSpacePos)); // Update "firstName"
      this.lastName(value.substring(lastSpacePos + 1)); // Update "lastName"
    }
  },
  owner: this
});
```

Comment: If you want to execute logic when the computed changes, I'd suggest to use `subscribe`. `self.valueView.subscribe(function(newValue) { /* logic */ })`. Use the `beforeChange` option if you need to use the old value.

Comment: I want execute logic when I read and write. I can see the example but it's using two observables.

Comment: Isn't it bad practice to update other observables inside a pureComputed?

Comment: I _think_ that only concerns the `read` method, but I might be wrong. I got the example from their own documentation though... The way I understand it, the `fullName` read method is only evaluated when there is an actual subscriber. And `read` is still a pure function right?